# How to generate a list of contemporaneous loans from loan level data?

Tags: pandas, reshape, data-analysis

I am trying to detect multiple borrowing in a loan level data set that looks as follows:

```
d = {'start_month': [1,2,4,1,14],
'customer': ['A','A','A','C','C'],
'branch': [1,2,3,2,1],
'maturity_month': [13,14,16,13,26]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to reshape these data into a month/branch panel that indicates for each branch i the branches j that are also currently loaning to the same customer as branch i. 
For branch i, loaning to the same customer as branch j in some month is defined as maturity_month_i >= maturity_month_j > start_month_i

```
d2 = {'start_month': [1,1,2,4,14],
 'branch': [1,2,2,3,1],
 'contemp_branch1':[0,0,1,1,0],
 'contemp_branch2':[0,0,0,1,0],
 'contemp_branch3':[0,0,0,0,0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfpES.png)

I assume that I will need to (i) generate a long data set, which, for every loan, lists all contemporaneous loans and their respective branches, and then (ii) reshape. I am struggling primarily with (i), especially since my data set is very large and I need an efficient solution.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `get_dummies`, `add_prefix` and `assign`:

```
df[['branch','start_month']].assign(**df.branch.astype(str).str.get_dummies()
                                        .add_prefix('contemp_branch'))
```

Output:

```
   branch  start_month  contemp_branch1  contemp_branch2  contemp_branch3
0       1            1                1                0                0
1       2            2                0                1                0
2       3            4                0                0                1
3       2            1                0                1                0
4       1           14                1                0                0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is coming close! Unfortunately, it doesn't yield exactly the output I am after. I suspect the code I am looking for to make use of the condition maturity_month_i >= maturity_month_j > start_month_i somehow. Any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Ruth Ruth can you include what your expected out should be for this sample output in your question.  Is it a new  dataframe, list,tuple and what are its contents based on this sample data.

Comment: Scott, I am expecting a new dataframe like that in the second sample code. I added a photo now (desired output link), hope that makes it clearer. Thank you!